# Adding labels to graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, figure

I am dealing with an excel file. I am plotting two graphs and trying to add labels. But in the first one labels do not show up. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Jack/Desktop/Final Excel.xlsx")

fig_1 = plt.figure(1, figsize=(70, 10))
ax1 = fig_1.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig_1.add_subplot(122)
t = list(df.iloc[[-1]])
r = np.array(t)

arrow1 = df. iloc[[0,1,2]].mean()
arrow2 = df.iloc[[9,10,11]].mean()
arrow3 = df.iloc[[18,19,20]].mean()
arrow4 = df.iloc[[36,37,38]].mean()

ax1.plot(r,arrow1, label='1')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
ax1.plot(r,arrow2, label='2')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
ax1.plot(r,arrow3, label='3')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
ax1.plot(r,arrow4, label='4')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

stone1 = df.iloc[[3,4,5]].mean()
stone2 = df.iloc[[12,13,14]].mean()
stone3 = df.iloc[[21,22,23]].mean()
stone4 = df.iloc[[39,40,41]].mean()

ax2.plot(r,stone1, label='1')
plt.legend(loc='upper center')
ax2.plot(r,stone2, label='2')
plt.legend(loc='upper center')
ax2.plot(r,stone3, label='3')
plt.legend(loc='upper center')
ax2.plot(r,stone4, label='4')

plt.figure()
plt.show()
```

I am only getting labels in the second chart but not in the first one. How could I add the desired labels on the first one as well? Thank you in advance! Have a nice day.

Comment: I think instead of using "plt.legend", use "ax1.legend" and "ax2.legend".

Comment: It actually worked. Thank you a lot for your valuable answer.